# Android - How to retrieve SQL-format date time regardless of Phone Calendar setting (Weird characters issue)

Tags: android, datetime

Our app has been working fine past few years to retrieve sql-format date time string from a lot of Android devices (with different locales/languages) to get string like `2020-06-04 11:22:33`. Until recently, there is one case where the phone return datetime string like this `২০২০-০৬-০৪ ০৮:০৮:৪২` when it was supposed to be around `4th June 2020 7.00+AM`. And we have no physical access to the phone.

From what I searched these are Bangladesh letters.

This is the code I used:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformatter_sqldatetime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String sqldatetime = dateformatter_sqldatetime.format(new Date());
```

Any idea how to make it return the correct date time? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, we found that it is called Bengali numbers.

We solved this without updating app native codes, in our server we do manual character replacement for character 1 to 9 , by referring to this thread: [Converting Numbers to Local (UTF8) Bengali numbers in JasperReports & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298730/converting-numbers-to-local-utf8-bengali-numbers-in-jasperreports-mysql)